# How is the IsReadOnly attribute used on ContentNote?

Tags: contentdocument, content, contentnote

I'm trying to create a read-only "enhanced note" and I see that there is a property on [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm) for `IsReadOnly` which would work perfectly for the use case but unfortunately:

```
Line: 1, Column: 17
Field is not writeable: ContentNote.IsReadOnly
```

I have been looking into what controls the read-only behavior that might exist on a `ContentNote` and I cannot identify what influences this attribute for it to return `true`.

- What makes an enhanced note read-only?
- Is there something on
  `ContentDocument` or `ContentDocumentVersion` that might influence
  it?

Comment: Are you able to find out on this? I am running into same issue where I need to create "Read-Only" notes

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not locate an answer to this.